# Count of elements in array

Tags: c, arrays

This is one of the simplest question on hackerearth, here the is problem statement:

> You are given a string S. Count the number of occurrences of all the digits in the string S.

But I cant figure out why my solution is not working, I guess it has some problem with the input array, please help me to figure it out. (I want this solution using arrays).

```
int i, j;
int digit[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int presence[10] = {0};
int inp[80];
scanf("%s", inp);
for(i = 0; i < strlen(inp); i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
       if(inp[i] == digit[j]) {
           presence[j]++;
       }
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\t%d\n",digit[i],presence[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think `char inp[80]` is better than `int inp[80];`

Comment: *"It's not working"* is not sufficient problem description. Please read on [mcve], and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: To begin with, your code doesn't contain any strings... You need to read a C book.

Comment: Holy... Is it so hard to indent your code?

Comment: @AndreKampling: "*`int presence[10]={0};` as you're setting the `10` to `0`*" err, what? The statement defines an array `presence` of 10 `int`s which are all initialised to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that by defining

```
int inp[80];
```

`scanf` stores the data properly in memory (maybe with a warning from the compiler), but then `inp[i]` is an integer made of several characters (bogus result of mapping characters on an integer data). You have to store your string in `char`:

```
char inp[80];
```

Second problem is that comparing character codes of digits won't match against actual numbers. Try substracting the ascii code of `'0'`:

```
if(inp[i]-'0' == digit[j]){
```

which can also be achieved without the `digit` table, or with any string size and without the double loop by deducing the digit from ASCII code directly:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(inp); i++) {
    if ((inp[i]>='0') && (inp[i]<='9') { 
           presence[inp[i]-'0']++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments your array `inp` should be a `char` array for it to be a string.

You don't need to use that inner loop to test if a character is a digit - you can use `isdigit` to test for that and subject `'0'` to find out which digit you've got.

And the way you're processing through the string is also very inefficient as you were calculating the length of the string each iteration of the loop. I've replaced that with a `char` pointer as that will point to the start of the string and keep going until what it's pointing to is the terminating NUL character.

```
int i;
int presence[10] = {0};
char inp[80], *p;

scanf("%s", inp);

for(p = inp; *p; p++) {
    if(isdigit(*p)) {
        presence[*p-'0']++;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d\t%d\n",i,presence[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understend correctly what you want, the code below could be your answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){ 
    int i, j;
    char digit[10] = "0123456789";
    int count[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    char inp[10];

    scanf("%s", inp);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(inp); i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(digit); j++) {
            if(inp[i] == digit[j]) {
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\t%d\n", i, count[i]);
    }
}
```

inp is the string you read

digit contains all possible digits (0 to 9)

count counts all appearences of the digits in the respective position.